Tkinter frame being weird with button spacing
So i have this script that im using to mess around with tkinter gui just to learn it and i have a frame that holds 3 buttons and i have the row and column setup so they have no gap and it works fine until i add anything thats in the row below that, what happens is the 2nd button and the 3rd get pulled to the other side of the program and the first button just sticks to the left side its really weird
Well ive tried to change the padding on the radio buttons which are causing the issue but it dosent seem to do like anything at all so i tried adding a columnspan to the buttons themself because i thought that would make it stick but nah

# Configuring all of the default GUI options
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Steppazer")
root.geometry("450x450")
root.resizable(True, True)

yer = IntVar()

# Creating the main notebook for gui
my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
my_notebook.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

# Creating all tabs and adding them to the main notebook
my_tab1 = ttk.Frame(my_notebook)
my_notebook.add(my_tab1, text="Lollll")
my_tab2 = ttk.Frame(my_notebook)
my_notebook.add(my_tab2, text="Lmaooo")

# Creating the frames
frame1 = LabelFrame(my_tab1, width=450, height=450, padx=5, pady=5, text="LabelFrameaz")
frame1.grid(padx=15, pady=15)
frame2 = LabelFrame(my_tab2, width=450, height=450, padx=5, pady=5)
frame2.grid(padx=15, pady=15)

# Creating Tab 1 Buttons
Button(frame1, text="Lollllerson", padx=5, pady=5, width=7, height=1)
Button.grid(row=1, column=0)
Button2(frame1, text="Ttheflip", padx=5, pady=5, width=7, height=1)
Button2.grid(row=1, column=2)
Button3(frame1, text="Wowza", padx=5, pady=5, width=7, height=1)
Button3.grid(row=1, column=3)


# Creating Radio Buttons
Radiobutton(frame1, text="Uno", variable=yer, value=1, padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=2, column=0)
Radiobutton(frame1, text="Dos", variable=yer, value=2, padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=2, column=1)
Radiobutton(frame1, text="Tres", variable=yer, value=3, padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()



until i add anything thats in the row below that, what happens is the
2nd button and the 3rd get pulled to the other side of the program and
the first button just sticks to the left side its really weird

Don't use the wildcard from tkinter import * Use import tkinter as tk, then use prefix tk. for every widget.
Declare variable for every widget. For example tk.Button should be btn = tk.Button.
The column should be column=0, column=1 and column=2. Not column=0, column=2, and column=3.
Snippet:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Steppazer")
root.geometry("450x450")
root.resizable(True, True)

yer = tk.IntVar()
:
:
:

# Creating the frames
frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(my_tab1, width=450, height=450,  text="LabelFrameaz")
frame1.grid(padx=15, pady=5)

frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(my_tab2, width=450, height=450, padx=5, pady=5)
frame2.grid(padx=15, pady=15)

# Creating Tab 1 Buttons
btn = tk.Button(frame1, text="Lollllerson", bg='red', padx=5, pady=5, width=7, height=1)
btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn2 = tk.Button(frame1, text="Ttheflip", padx=5, pady=5, width=7, height=1)
btn2.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn3 = tk.Button(frame1, text="Wowza", padx=5, pady=5, width=7, height=1)
btn3.grid(row=1, column=2)

# Creating Radio Buttons
tk.Radiobutton(frame1, text="Uno", variable=yer, value=1, padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Radiobutton(frame1, text="Dos", variable=yer, value=2, padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=2, column=1)
tk.Radiobutton(frame1, text="Tres", variable=yer, value=3, padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()

Screenshot:

